# Eigen convert Matrix4x4 to Matrix3x3

Tags: c++, math, eigen

I cannot get my head around this problem to convert Matrix4x4 to Matrix3x3 using Eigen.
For example if I try this it fails:

```
Matrix4f m;
m << 1, 2, 3, 4,
     5, 6, 7, 8,
     9, 10, 11, 12,
     13, 14, 15, 16;
Matrix3f m2 = m.block(0,0,3,3);
```

Is it possible to return different type with block operations or if there is any other quick workaround for this problem?

Comment: Your code compiles and runs seamlessly with Eigen version 3.1 and gcc-4.7.1. If not for you, you can try a static cast via `Eigen::Matrix3f m2 = static_cast<Eigen::Matrix3f>(m.block(0,0,3,3));`

Comment: Thanks I upgraded to Eigen 3.2.1 and it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to Eigen 3.2.1 fixed my problem.